# Преобразование XML в другой XML

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl

Из этого:

```
<cs:message xmlns:cs="http://www.URL.ru">
    <cs:header app-from="sql2" app-to="common/send-outgoing-message"
        correlation-id="ID:10424982-83.139.14.107(f4:d7:e7:30:bf:fb)-61573-1554201529201"
        destination="re1"
        message-id="ID:10425004-83.139.14.107(f4:d7:e7:30:bf:fb)-61573-1554201529551"
        submit-timestamp="2019-04-02 14:38:49" type="Status"/>
    <cs:status status="Executed">
        <cs:param name="Result" type="XML">
            <cs:value>
                <records>
                    <record number="1">
                        <ID>458161462</ID>
                        <SERVICE_ID>612911</SERVICE_ID>
                        <MSISDN>37477704529</MSISDN>
                        <BODY>&lt;mdata
                            data="000000DD000000040000000010B51C920005005768617473417070000101333734373737303435323900030000003139303430323130343834363030302B0001000000993C233E20596F757220576861747341707020636F64653A203937332D3735350A0A596F752063616E20616C736F20746170206F6E2074686973206C696E6B20746F2076657269667920796F75722070686F6E653A20762E77686174736170702E636F6D2F3937333735350A0A446F6E2774207368617265207468697320636F64652077697468206F74686572730A3473674C71317035735636"
                            description="(#) Your WhatsApp code: 973-755 You can also tap on this
                            link to verify your phone: v.whatsapp.com/973755 Don't share this code
                            with others 4sgLq1p5sV6"/&gt;</BODY>
                        <PRIORITY>1</PRIORITY>
                        <DELIVERY_REPORT>0</DELIVERY_REPORT>
                        <SPLITTING>null</SPLITTING>
                        <PREFERRED_MODULE_NAME>lcrrouter1</PREFERRED_MODULE_NAME>
                        <PREFERRED_USER_FROM>WhatsApp</PREFERRED_USER_FROM>
                        <STATUS_ID>0</STATUS_ID>
                        <TRANSMISSION_TRIALS>0</TRANSMISSION_TRIALS>
                        <IN_SMS_EXT_ID>null</IN_SMS_EXT_ID>
                        <CHARGING>null</CHARGING>
                        <WCS_CONTENT_TYPE_ID>12</WCS_CONTENT_TYPE_ID>
                        <FLASH_SMS>0</FLASH_SMS>
                        <ENCODING>0</ENCODING>
                        <PARTNER_CHARGE>0</PARTNER_CHARGE>
                        <PARTNER_ID>21927</PARTNER_ID>
                    </record>
                    <record number="2">
                        <ID>458161464</ID>
                        <SERVICE_ID>638118</SERVICE_ID>
                        <MSISDN>37493765423</MSISDN>
                        <BODY>Mekangamya ogtagorcman kod - 3137</BODY>
                        <PRIORITY>1</PRIORITY>
                        <DELIVERY_REPORT>1</DELIVERY_REPORT>
                        <SPLITTING>null</SPLITTING>
                        <PREFERRED_MODULE_NAME>armentel-smpp</PREFERRED_MODULE_NAME>
                        <PREFERRED_USER_FROM>9999</PREFERRED_USER_FROM>
                        <STATUS_ID>0</STATUS_ID>
                        <TRANSMISSION_TRIALS>0</TRANSMISSION_TRIALS>
                        <IN_SMS_EXT_ID>12345</IN_SMS_EXT_ID>
                        <CHARGING>1</CHARGING>
                        <WCS_CONTENT_TYPE_ID>10</WCS_CONTENT_TYPE_ID>
                        <FLASH_SMS>0</FLASH_SMS>
                        <ENCODING>0</ENCODING>
                        <PARTNER_CHARGE>0</PARTNER_CHARGE>
                        <PARTNER_ID>20148</PARTNER_ID>
                    </record>
                </records>
            </cs:value>
        </cs:param>
    </cs:status>
</cs:message>
```

Нужно сделать это:

```
<cs:messages xmlns:cs="http://www.URL.ru">
    <cs:message xmlns:cs="http://www.URL.ru">
        <cs:header charging="false" content-type="SubmitSM" delivery-notification-requested="false" data="000000DD000000040000000010B51C920005005768617473417070000101333734373737303435323900030000003139303430323130343834363030302B0001000000993C233E20596F757220576861747341707020636F64653A203937332D3735350A0A596F752063616E20616C736F20746170206F6E2074686973206C696E6B20746F2076657269667920796F75722070686F6E653A20762E77686174736170702E636F6D2F3937333735350A0A446F6E2774207368617265207468697320636F64652077697468206F74686572730A3473674C71317035735636"
            description="(#) Your WhatsApp code: 973-755 You can also tap on this link to verify your phone: v.whatsapp.com/973755 Don't share this code with others 4sgLq1p5sV6" destination="lcrrouter1" direct-display="false"
            out-sms-id="458161462" partner-id="21927" priority="1" real-module-name="lcrrouter1"
            reply-to="@re-stat$common|Transmitted@re-stat-transmitted$common" service-id="612911"
            source-ton="5" type="User" user-from="WhatsApp" user-to="37477704529"/>
        <cs:body>000000DD000000040000000010B51C920005005768617473417070000101333734373737303435323900030000003139303430323130343834363030302B0001000000993C233E20596F757220576861747341707020636F64653A203937332D3735350A0A596F752063616E20616C736F20746170206F6E2074686973206C696E6B20746F2076657269667920796F75722070686F6E653A20762E77686174736170702E636F6D2F3937333735350A0A446F6E2774207368617265207468697320636F64652077697468206F74686572730A3473674C71317035735636</cs:body>
    </cs:message>
    <cs:message xmlns:cs="http://www.wsoft.ru">
        <cs:header charging="true" content-type="PlainText" delivery-notification-requested="true"
            destination="armentel-smpp" direct-display="false"
            out-sms-id="458161464" partner-id="20148" priority="1" real-module-name="armentel-smpp"
            reply-to="@re-stat$common|Transmitted@re-stat-transmitted$common" service-id="638118"
            source-ton="0" type="User" user-from="9999" user-to="37493765423#12345"/>
        <cs:body>Mekangamya ogtagorcman kod - 3137</cs:body>
    </cs:message>
</cs:messages>
```

Получилось дойти только до того, что выводятся значения из первого документа, но не понимаю как избавиться от ненужных данных (по типу SPLITTING, SERVICE_ID, которых нет в документе, который должен получиться), как изменить уже существующие данные, например CHARGING в исходном документе NULL, а в нужном =true) и как добавить body и header.

Мой код:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <xsl:template match="record">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each select="*">
                <xsl:attribute name="{local-name(.)}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:variable name="elem-name" select="local-name(.)"/>
                <xsl:for-each select="@*">
                    <xsl:attribute name="{concat($elem-name,'-',local-name(.))}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Какая у вас версия XSLT: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 или 4.0?

Comment: Версия 2.0, спасибо большое, всё как нужно, хотел ещё спросить, каким образом можно перемещать атрибуты, например charging="false" поставить в самое начало после <cs:header ?

Comment: и как переименовать сам атрибут, оставив при этом значение, допустим в первом документе есть "<MSISDN>37477704529</MSISDN>", а во втором должно получиться  "user-to="37477704529"" ?

Comment: _перемещать атрибуты_ - это не имеет смысла, т. к. порядок атрибутов в xml не определён. [Стандарт](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-starttags) Note that the order of attribute specifications in a start-tag or empty-element tag is not significant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот реализация в XSLT 2.0.

Возможно, вам понадобится подправить XSLT в соответствии с вашими потребностями.

> каким образом можно перемещать атрибуты, например charging="false"
> поставить в самое начало после <cs:header ?

Атрибуты уникальны внутри элементов XML. У них нет понятия о сортировке или местоположении.

> как переименовать сам атрибут, оставив при этом значение, допустим в
> первом документе есть "37477704529", а во втором
> должно получиться "user-to="37477704529"" ?

Для этого я добавил переменную `$elem-name` в XSLT.

**Входной XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<cs:message xmlns:cs="http://www.URL.ru">
    <cs:header app-from="sql2" app-to="common/send-outgoing-message"
               correlation-id="ID:10424982-83.139.14.107(f4:d7:e7:30:bf:fb)-61573-1554201529201"
               destination="re1"
               message-id="ID:10425004-83.139.14.107(f4:d7:e7:30:bf:fb)-61573-1554201529551"
               submit-timestamp="2019-04-02 14:38:49" type="Status"/>
    <cs:status status="Executed">
        <cs:param name="Result" type="XML">
            <cs:value>
                <records>
                    <record number="1">
                        <ID>458161462</ID>
                        <SERVICE_ID>612911</SERVICE_ID>
                        <MSISDN>37477704529</MSISDN>
                        <BODY>&lt;mdata
                            data="000000DD000000040000000010B51C920005005768617473417070000101333734373737303435323900030000003139303430323130343834363030302B0001000000993C233E20596F757220576861747341707020636F64653A203937332D3735350A0A596F752063616E20616C736F20746170206F6E2074686973206C696E6B20746F2076657269667920796F75722070686F6E653A20762E77686174736170702E636F6D2F3937333735350A0A446F6E2774207368617265207468697320636F64652077697468206F74686572730A3473674C71317035735636"
                            description="(#) Your WhatsApp code: 973-755 You can also tap on this
                            link to verify your phone: v.whatsapp.com/973755 Don't share this code
                            with others 4sgLq1p5sV6"/&gt;</BODY>
                        <PRIORITY>1</PRIORITY>
                        <DELIVERY_REPORT>0</DELIVERY_REPORT>
                        <SPLITTING>null</SPLITTING>
                        <PREFERRED_MODULE_NAME>lcrrouter1</PREFERRED_MODULE_NAME>
                        <PREFERRED_USER_FROM>WhatsApp</PREFERRED_USER_FROM>
                        <STATUS_ID>0</STATUS_ID>
                        <TRANSMISSION_TRIALS>0</TRANSMISSION_TRIALS>
                        <IN_SMS_EXT_ID>null</IN_SMS_EXT_ID>
                        <CHARGING>null</CHARGING>
                        <WCS_CONTENT_TYPE_ID>12</WCS_CONTENT_TYPE_ID>
                        <FLASH_SMS>0</FLASH_SMS>
                        <ENCODING>0</ENCODING>
                        <PARTNER_CHARGE>0</PARTNER_CHARGE>
                        <PARTNER_ID>21927</PARTNER_ID>
                    </record>
                    <record number="2">
                        <ID>458161464</ID>
                        <SERVICE_ID>638118</SERVICE_ID>
                        <MSISDN>37493765423</MSISDN>
                        <BODY>Mekangamya ogtagorcman kod - 3137</BODY>
                        <PRIORITY>1</PRIORITY>
                        <DELIVERY_REPORT>1</DELIVERY_REPORT>
                        <SPLITTING>null</SPLITTING>
                        <PREFERRED_MODULE_NAME>armentel-smpp</PREFERRED_MODULE_NAME>
                        <PREFERRED_USER_FROM>9999</PREFERRED_USER_FROM>
                        <STATUS_ID>0</STATUS_ID>
                        <TRANSMISSION_TRIALS>0</TRANSMISSION_TRIALS>
                        <IN_SMS_EXT_ID>12345</IN_SMS_EXT_ID>
                        <CHARGING>1</CHARGING>
                        <WCS_CONTENT_TYPE_ID>10</WCS_CONTENT_TYPE_ID>
                        <FLASH_SMS>0</FLASH_SMS>
                        <ENCODING>0</ENCODING>
                        <PARTNER_CHARGE>0</PARTNER_CHARGE>
                        <PARTNER_ID>20148</PARTNER_ID>
                    </record>
                </records>
            </cs:value>
        </cs:param>
    </cs:status>
</cs:message>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:cs="http://www.URL.ru">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="cs:message">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="record">
        <cs:message xmlns:cs="http://www.URL.ru">
            <cs:header>
                <xsl:for-each select="*[not(local-name(.)=('ID','BODY','SPLITTING'))]">
                    <xsl:variable name="elem-name">
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="local-name(.)='MSISDN'">user-to</xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                <xsl:value-of select="lower-case(replace(local-name(.),'_','-'))"/>
                            </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:variable name="elem-value" select="."/>
                    <xsl:attribute name="{$elem-name}">
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="local-name(.)='CHARGING' and $elem-value='null'">false</xsl:when>
                            <xsl:when test="local-name(.)='CHARGING' and $elem-value='1'">true</xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                            </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:for-each>
                <cs:body>
                    <xsl:value-of select="BODY"/>
                </cs:body>
            </cs:header>
        </cs:message>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Выходной XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cs:message xmlns:cs="http://www.URL.ru">
    <cs:message>
        <cs:header service-id="612911" user-to="37477704529" priority="1"
                   delivery-report="0" preferred-module-name="lcrrouter1"
                   preferred-user-from="WhatsApp" status-id="0"
                   transmission-trials="0" in-sms-ext-id="null" charging="false"
                   wcs-content-type-id="12" flash-sms="0" encoding="0"
                   partner-charge="0" partner-id="21927">
            <cs:body>&lt;mdata
                            data="000000DD000000040000000010B51C920005005768617473417070000101333734373737303435323900030000003139303430323130343834363030302B0001000000993C233E20596F757220576861747341707020636F64653A203937332D3735350A0A596F752063616E20616C736F20746170206F6E2074686973206C696E6B20746F2076657269667920796F75722070686F6E653A20762E77686174736170702E636F6D2F3937333735350A0A446F6E2774207368617265207468697320636F64652077697468206F74686572730A3473674C71317035735636"
                            description="(#) Your WhatsApp code: 973-755 You can also tap on this
                            link to verify your phone: v.whatsapp.com/973755 Don't share this code
                            with others 4sgLq1p5sV6"/&gt;</cs:body>
        </cs:header>
    </cs:message>
    <cs:message>
        <cs:header service-id="638118" user-to="37493765423" priority="1"
                   delivery-report="1" preferred-module-name="armentel-smpp"
                   preferred-user-from="9999" status-id="0"
                   transmission-trials="0" in-sms-ext-id="12345" charging="true"
                   wcs-content-type-id="10" flash-sms="0" encoding="0"
                   partner-charge="0" partner-id="20148">
            <cs:body>Mekangamya ogtagorcman kod - 3137</cs:body>
        </cs:header>
    </cs:message>
</cs:message>
```

Comment: Я обновил XSD. 